# Jenkinsfile Creating Scratch Org Failing

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, salesforce, bitbucket

I am trying to create a Continuous Integration between BitBucket and Salesforce using Jenkins and I am having trouble with the Scratch Org creation. The Jenkinsfile I BELIEVE is set up correctly. Here it is:

```
node {

def SF_JENKINSUSER = env.SF_JENKINS_USER
def SF_USERNAME = env.SF_JENKINS_USER + '.' + env.SF_DEV
def SF_URL = env.SF_TESTURL
def SF_PROD = env.SF_PRODURL
def SF_DEV_HUB = env.SF_DEVHUB

stage('Checkout Source') {
    checkout scm
}

withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {    
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'SF_CONSUMER_KEY_BIND', variable: 'SF_CONSUMER_KEY'), file(credentialsId: 'SERVER_KEY_CREDENTALS_ID', variable: 'server_key_file')]) {
        stage('Authorize DevHub Org') {
            try {
                rc = command "sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -r ${SF_PROD} -i ${SF_CONSUMER_KEY} -u ${SF_JENKINSUSER} -f ${server_key_file} --setdefaultdevhubusername -a ${SF_DEV_HUB}"
                if ( rc != 0 ) {
                    echo '========== ERROR: ' + rc
                    error 'Salesforce org authorization failed.'
                }
                else {
                    command "sfdx force:org:list"
                    echo '========== LOGGED IN =========='
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                echo "========== DEVHUB AUTHORIZATION FAILURE: ${err} =========="
            }           
        }

        // Create a new scratch org to test the repo
        stage('Create Test Scratch Org') {
            try {
                rc = command "sfdx force:org:create -s -f config\\project-scratch-def.json -a TestScratch -w 10 -d 1"
                if (rc != 0) {
                    error 'Salesforce test scratch org creation failed.'
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                echo "========== SCRATCH ORG CREATION FAILURE: ${err} =========="
            }                
        }
    }  
}   }   
def command(script) {
if ( isUnix() ) {
    return sh(returnStatus: true, script: script);
} 
else {
    return bat(returnStatus: true, script: script);
}
```

Apologies about the formatting there. Now, the results of this I cannot figure out. It says the connected status of the orgs are JwtGrantFailure and it's looking for a server.key file instead of the scratch json file in the command line. Here are the pertinent parts of the output from this job:

```
E:\DevOps_Root\JENKINS\workspace\TestingCIPipeline2>sfdx force:org:list 
=== Orgs
 ALIAS     USERNAME                       ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
(D)  DevHub    sa.jenkins@[...].com           00D300000000UicEAE  JwtGrantError


 No active scratch orgs found. Specify --all to see all scratch orgs
[Pipeline] echo
========== LOGGED IN ==========
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Create Test Scratch Org)
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] bat

E:\DevOps_Root\JENKINS\workspace\TestingCIPipeline2>sfdx force:org:create -s -f config\project-scratch-def.json -a TestScratch -w 10 -d 1 
ERROR running force:org:create:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'E:\DevOps_Root\JENKINS\workspace\Pipe@tmp\secretFiles\e0ab232f-1958-42d1-b3bb-aed5e00a562f\server.key'
[Pipeline] echo
========== SCRATCH ORG COMMAND FAILURE: 1
```

Why would the job be looking for the server.key file when I have already run the withCredentials successfully? What am I missing here?

Any insights would be greatly appredciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so .. this one confounded me for a while, but I finally got the script to create a scratch org.

I logged into the Jenkins Virtual Server through Remote Desktop Connection, opened windows explorer, navigated to the Jenkins User .sfdx folder and deleted the following files:

```
alias.json
key.json
user@domain.json
stash.json
```

After I did that, I made some updates in the Jenkinsfile and pushed the changes up to the repository. The job ran, and the Scratch Org was created.

My new issue is trying to figure out how to have the same job run again because we will have multiple repos working this single job.

Anyway, I hope this helps some of you out who are facing the same issue.